# Node JS body-parser get rawBody and body

Tags: node.js, body-parser

I'm currently implementing the body parser in a way that is mentioned below

```
 var rawBodySaver = function (req, res, buf, encoding) {
        if (buf && buf.length) {
            req.rawBody = buf.toString(encoding || 'utf8');
        }
    }
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}))
    app.use(bodyParser.json({ verify: rawBodySaver }));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ verify: rawBodySaver, extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.raw({ verify: rawBodySaver, type: function () { return true } }));
```

Previously, it was just `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}))` and I got my data in req.body.

But due to some new requirements I had to use rawBody. Is there any way where I can get data in their respective formats in  both `rawBody` and `body`

Right now, only either of `rawBody` or `body` works. Both don not work together.

Comment: Just to confirm, you want `req.body` to be body parsed as `urlencoded` and also have `req.rawBody` as the original body?

Comment: Yes. If it's possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While a tad hacky, I liked your idea of using the `verify` function to store the raw body somewhere. I believe your problem was caused by calling `bodyParser.*` too many times. It appears that only the last call does anything.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

function rawBodySaver (req, res, buf, encoding) {
  if (buf && buf.length) {
    req.rawBody = buf.toString(encoding || 'utf8')
  }
}

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
  verify: rawBodySaver
}))

app.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(`rawBody: ${req.rawBody}`)
  console.log(`parsed Body: ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`)
  res.sendStatus(200)
})

// This is just to test the above code.
const request = require('supertest')
request(app)
.post('/')
.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
.send('user=tobi')
.expect(200, () => {})
```

This prints:

```
rawBody: user=tobi
parsed Body: {"user":"tobi"}
```

Comment: Simply fantastic! Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Please keep in mind that it will double (roughly) usage of memory by request body since you store two copies of it. The `verify` function is intended for in place actions.